# stuck on loading screen

Tags: flutter, dart

this is the problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwoAO.png)

I use firebase to store the data

this is my code :

[Homepage.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8QPH.png)

[main.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihKlH.png)

I already follow all the step but still get the error.

I expect this. I don't know how to explain what i expecting but I have the picture that's what I want. I hope you can help me guys

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12W4l.jpg)

Comment: You are creating the stream in the stream parameter of the StreamBuilder, which suffers from the same problem as this: Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Answer (score 0):

You don't have permission to access the data from firestore, maybe you have set up the firestore in production mode when creating. To set this in test mode you can add this to your security rules.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

This will make your firestore database accessible to anyone, this means anyone can read or write to your database.

Also, create a view for the error page, so you don't have to stick to the loading screen. You can make it by adding an additional else statement.